# Detection of screenshot taken?

Tags: java, android, screenshot

Is there any way i can detect in my service when user takes screenshot of his android device?

The basic idea is whenever user takes screenshot of his device a popup will be displayed asking user to upload image to facebook, twitter etc.

Comment: I assume that you are the one that make that service. Do you put the screenshot on a `Bitmap` object? Can you please help us by some chunk of codes?

Answer (score 4):

This is untested, but you may want to try the FileObserver class.

Point it at the screenshots folder and wait for a CREATE event.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html

Comment: Just FYI I think file observers will work but some versions are buggy with it like android 6.0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237314/fileobserver-and-contentobserver-not-working-in-android-marshmallow